# Gaussian Sums of a Dirichlet's Character

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In Davenport's chapter 9, They defined

$$\tau(\chi)=\sum_{m=1}^{q} \chi(m) e_q(m)$$
Further if $(n,q)=1$, then we have that $$\chi(n)\tau(\overline{\chi})=\sum_{h=1}^{q} \overline{\chi}(m) e_q(nh)$$ and then they wrote that this gives the desired expression for
$\text{ }\chi(n)\text{ }$  provided $\text{ }(n,q)=1$.

My question is, we have
$$
\chi(n) = \frac{\sum_{h=1}^{q} \overline{\chi}(m) e_q(nh)}{\tau(\overline{\chi})}
$$ but when we are computing the RHS, we need $\overline{\chi}(h)$ so we know what is the value of $\chi(n)$ and so why are we computing $\chi(n)$ with such a complicated expression.

Comment: Clean up the roles of $h$ and $m$ in the second and third equations. A sum over $h$ has terms $\overline{\chi}(m)$?

Answer (score 1):

One way that sums like $\sum_m \chi(m)\psi(nm/q)$ appear (writing $\psi(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$) in the functional equation for Dirichlet $L$-functions, whether done classically or as in Iwasawa-Tate.

The point is that the $\chi$ (or $\overline{\chi}$...) comes out of the indicated sum. Then the Gauss sum, divided by $\sqrt{\pm q}$, is the "$\epsilon$-factor" in the functional equation of the corresponding $L$-function(s). (Yes, for $\chi$ not real-valued, the functional equation relates $L(1-s,\chi)$ and $L(s,\overline{\chi})$
...)

Yes, as @KCd says, this gives a sort of "integral representation" of $\chi$, though it's not clear to me that this is what extends $\chi$ to an idele class character.

More explicitly: to prove analytic continuation and functional equation of $L(s,\chi)=\sum_n \chi(n)/n^s$, the Riemann-IwasawaTate approach is to use an integral representation of the $L$-function, with suitable Gamma factors: for $\chi$ *even* (for $\chi$ odd it's slightly different), it is
$$
\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)L(s) \;=\; {1\over 2}\int_0^\infty y^{s/2} \sum_n\chi(n)e^{-\pi n^2 y}\;dy/y
$$
Applying Poisson summation to that linear combination of theta functions inside the integral (to prove the functional equation of that linear combination) spits out the Gauss sum, etc.

Comment: I cannot understand this at all. Can you explain it in a simpler language?

Comment: @permutation_matrix the material you cannot understand at all mostly appears later in Davenport's chapter 9, so just keep reading that chapter and then you'll understand what Paul's reply is describing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of the point might be that on the right side, $n$ is not appearing inside $\chi$-values, and where $n$ does appear it could be a real number, so this equation can serve as a way of *defining* $\chi(n)$ when $n$ is a real number.

Compare with the equation
$$
n! = \int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\,dx
$$
for $n \geq 0$ in $\mathbf Z$. On the right side, $n$ can be a nonnegative real number, so we can use the right side to *define* $n!$ when $n$ is a nonnegative real number, e.g., $(1/2)! := \int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x}\,dx$.

EDIT: I looked in Davenport Chapter 9, and he explains directly in the second paragraph of that chapter why he wants such a formula for $\chi(n)$:

> We need the expression for $\chi(n)$ as a linear combination of imaginary exponentials $e_q(mn)$, which we used earlier in §1 [(4) and (5)]

The formula you ask about was derived when $(n,q) = 1$, but Davenport then immediately shows right afterwards that when $\chi$ is primitive that formula is *also* true when $(n,q) > 1$: it's true for all integers $n$, no matter what $(n,q)$ is. On pp. 66-67, Davenport uses that formula to show the Gauss sum of each primitive character mod $q$ has absolute value $\sqrt{q}$, and on the next few pages he uses this formula for $\chi(n)$ for all $n$ (when $\chi$ is primitive) in order to obtain the functional equation of the Dirichle $L$-function of $\chi$.

In short, the answer to your question is: *be patient*. Just read ahead, pay close attention, and you'll see the formula for $\chi(n)$ used!

Comment: no, Davenport's book has mentioned that $(n,q)=1$ so I will assume that $n$ is a natural number only

Comment: I have updated my answer to indicate how Davenport uses the formula.  It's all in that chapter. Have you kept reading ahead, or did you stop at the formula because you didn't see right away why it might be useful?

Comment: @permutation_matrix your comment above sounds as if you wrote the question ("no, Davenport's book has mentioned..., so I will assume..."), but your username is not the username of the OP.  Are you using two different accounts here?

Comment: the OP has clearly mentioned $(n,q)=1$